# How to convert arrays of times (with start/end and overlaps) to a 'timeline'?

Tags: algorithm, time

For example, let say i have an array of times as show below, each of which has a start and end time

format: **hours : minutes : seconds**

```
00:00:00 - 06:00:00
06:05:00 - 15:00:00
06:00:00 - 20:00:00
00:00:00 - 23:59:00
```

Now, i want to convert it to:

```
00:00:00 - 06:00:00
06:00:00 - 06:05:00
06:05:00 - 15:00:00
15:00:00 - 20:00:00
20:00:00 - 23:59:00
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: programming language?

Comment: currently php, but it doesn't matter

Comment: Make a list of all the timestamps, order chronologically, remove duplicates, then create ranges 1-2, 2-3, 3-4, 4-5...

Comment: chronologically on the start_time only?

Comment: @m69, u mean flatten the start/end time to a list of all these times?

Comment: @AdngTyl indeed, flatten to a single list of timestamps.

Comment: @m69, cool, already on it. seems to make sense! it's a bit late, can't think straight :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, you need to sort all the time intervals.

I don't know if these intervals can wrap, so I guess if they wrap, the best to do is sort them by the earliest end time, otherwise sort by earliest start time.

after the sorting, let's say you get an array  of intervals A = [a0, a1, ..., an]

then what you want is an array B such that:

> B[0] = (a0.begin, a0.end)
>
> B[1] = (a0.end, a1.begin)
>
> B[2] = (a1.begin, a1.end)
> ...

so the algorithm becomes simple when you notice that you just need to store the last guy who was used to start the next B[i]

```
function next( 2-tuple T ) -> 2-tuple {
    if(T.second == 0) {
        return 2-tuple(T.first, 1)
    }
    return 2-tiple(T.first + 1, 0)
}     

function Solution( array A ) -> array {
    let n = number of elements in A
    let index = 0
    let last = (0,0)
    while( last != (n,2) ){
        B[index] = (last, next(last))
    }
    return B
}
```

hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, got the solution from @m69 comments. If he post an answer l'll accept his, else yours. Cheers